# dataframe to_datetime not reading dates correctly

Tags: dataframe, python-datetime

Part of an excel file is as below.

```
Action Date1               Action Date2
15.06.2018 - 06:06:30   17.06.2018 - 15:52:35
09.07.2018 - 10:12:13   09.07.2018 - 11:39:42
09.08.2018 - 15:21:45   
10.07.2018 - 10:00:13   00.00.0000 - 00:00:00
```

......

I want to extract the latest action dates and I have the following codes

```
dates = df.fillna(axis=1, method='ffill')
df['Latest date'] = dates[dates.columns[-1]]
```

But this codes returns the correct dates as below.

```
2018-06-17 15:52:35
2018-09-07 11:39:42
2018-09-08 15:21:45
2018-10-07 10:00:13
```

.....

I tried

```
df['Latest date']=pd.to_datetime(df['Latest date'],format="%d%m%Y")
```

but it still gives me the same outcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use parameter `format`, check [`http://strftime.org/`](http://strftime.org/):

```
df['Latest date']=pd.to_datetime(df['Latest date'],format="%d.%m.%Y - %H:%M:%S")
```

Or parameter `dayfirst=True`:

```
df['Latest date']=pd.to_datetime(df['Latest date'], dayfirst=True)
```

---

```
print (df)
          Latest date
0 2018-06-15 06:06:30
1 2018-07-16 08:53:49
2 2018-07-09 10:12:13
3 2018-08-09 15:21:45
```

EDIT: Add parameter `errors='coerce'` for convert not parseable values to `NaT`:

```
df = df.apply(lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x,format="%d.%m.%Y - %H:%M:%S", errors='coerce'))
dates = df.ffill(axis=1)
df['Latest date'] = dates.iloc[:, -1]
print (df)
        Action Date1        Action Date2         Latest date
0 2018-06-15 06:06:30 2018-06-17 15:52:35 2018-06-17 15:52:35
1 2018-07-09 10:12:13 2018-07-09 11:39:42 2018-07-09 11:39:42
2 2018-08-09 15:21:45                 NaT 2018-08-09 15:21:45
3 2018-07-10 10:00:13                 NaT 2018-07-10 10:00:13
```

Comment: HI I have updated my question. I think the problem is actually fillna method changed the dates. I don't know how to specify date formats when forward fill na.

Comment: Thanks Jezrael! It solves my problem. I have also worked out using this to solve it:df=pd.to_datetime(df.stack(),dayfirst=True).unstack()